# how to populate 6 java arrays for each jbutton click?

Tags: java

i have 6 arrays , i declare counter  as instance variable and i use this counter inside jButton handler to populate the 6 array for different value each time i click the button getting the value from jTextField , but it always populate them all with the first vale , what is the problem ???

```
    private void jButton6ActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {                                         

         while (ctr1<6)
             {

            arr1[ctr1]= Double.parseDouble(jTextField18.getText());
            arr2[ctr1]=Double.parseDouble(jTextField19.getText());
            arr3[ctr1]=Double.parseDouble(jTextField20.getText());
            arr4[ctr1]=Double.parseDouble(jTextField21.getText());
            arr5[ctr1]=Double.parseDouble(jTextField22.getText());
            arr6[ctr1]=Double.parseDouble(jTextField23.getText());
            arr7[ctr1]=Double.parseDouble(jTextField24.getText());
            arr8[ctr1]=Double.parseDouble(jTextField25.getText());
            arr9[ctr1]=Double.parseDouble(jTextField26.getText());
           arr10[ctr1]=Double.parseDouble(jTextField27.getText());
           arr11[ctr1]=Double.parseDouble(jTextField28.getText());

            ctr1++;
          }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using linear console coding techniques within what should be an event-driven Swing GUI, and that won't work. So get rid of the while loop, and instead use the counter variable alone, filling the array item based on the counter. Also, you would do much better with 2 dimensional array of number and of JTextFields.

So, this would be better:

```
private void jButton6ActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
    if (ctrl < 6) {
        arr1[ctr1]= Double.parseDouble(jTextField18.getText());
        arr2[ctr1]=Double.parseDouble(jTextField19.getText());
        arr3[ctr1]=Double.parseDouble(jTextField20.getText());
        arr4[ctr1]=Double.parseDouble(jTextField21.getText());
        arr5[ctr1]=Double.parseDouble(jTextField22.getText());
        arr6[ctr1]=Double.parseDouble(jTextField23.getText());
        arr7[ctr1]=Double.parseDouble(jTextField24.getText());
        arr8[ctr1]=Double.parseDouble(jTextField25.getText());
        arr9[ctr1]=Double.parseDouble(jTextField26.getText());
        arr10[ctr1]=Double.parseDouble(jTextField27.getText());
        arr11[ctr1]=Double.parseDouble(jTextField28.getText());
    }
    ctrl++;
}
```

but even better still would be to use a 2D array of doubles and an array of JTextFields:

```
private void jButton6ActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
    if (ctrl < 6) {
        for (int i = 0; i < myCtrlArray.length; i++) {
            myCtrlArray[i][ctrl] = Double.parseDouble(myTextFieldArray[i].getText());
        }
    }
    ctrl++;
}
```